# jQuery - small screen navigation. Next and prev button href based on current window url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design, web-frontend

I have sidebar which disappears for iPad screens and smaller being replaced by next and previous arrows.

Basically, I want to take the current page URL, slit it from the domain and compare it to the anchor tags in the sidebar. Once the correct page has been found fill the 'previous' icon href with the href of the anchor tag before the 'current page' tag in the sidebar and fill the 'next' icon href with the href of the anchor tag that comes after.

**sidebar.html** (just a couple of lines but real sidebar a lot longer) **-**

```
<nav class="main-nav">
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">

<li>
<a href="{% url 'index:pg_1' %}" id="sub_1" ><h5>
{{title_1}}<span class=></span></h5></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="{% url 'index:pg_2' %}" id="sub_1" ><h5>
{{title_2}}<span class=></span></h5></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="{% url 'index:pg_3' %}" id="sub_1"><h5>
{{title_3}}<span class=></span></h5></a>
</li>

<li>
<a href="{% url 'index:pg_4' %}" id="sub_1"><h5>
{{title_4}}<span class=></span></h5></a>
</li>
```

**icons -**

```
<i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-5x prev" aria-hidden="true">
  <a class="left" href="#"></a>
</i>
<i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-5x next" aria-hidden="true">
<a href="#" class="right"></a> 
</i>
```

**jQuery -**

```
$(function(){
console.log("nav for sm screens is ready");
// var url; 
var x; 
var url; 
var page_url = window.location.pathname;
page_url.split('/');
console.log(page_url);
url = $("a#sub_1").attr("href"); // Gets all 'a' tags with id of 'sub_1' (all of them) 
console.log("we have urls "); 
for (x in url){                // loops through them
    if (page_url == url){      // matches page url with a url in sidebar 
      console.log("we have a url that is the same as the page url")
      console.log(url)
      if ($(this).closest("li a").prev().length) {  // code usually breaks down here, checking if an anchor tag exists before current selection or not
        console.log("there are no links before this")
        $(".prev").hide();   // if no anchor tag exists before this tag, hide previous.
        console.log("left is hidden");
        $(".right").prop("href", $(this).next("a").prop("href"));  // set 'next' to href of next anchor tag.  
        console.log("we have next link");

      };
    };
};
});
```

I've tried using `closest()`, `parent()`, `parents()` and a couple of other variations but nothing seems to work.

Comment: What are you seeing in the console? Don't you need `var parts = page_url.split('/');` to capture the resulting array?

Comment: The `id` attributes should be unique. Hence, use of `sub_1` for all will cause issues. Would advise using `class`: `<a href="{% url 'index:pg_1' %}" id="sub_1" class="sub-link" >`, and `<a href="{% url 'index:pg_2' %}" id="sub_2" class="sub-link">`, then use `$(".sub-link")` selector.

Comment: @Twisty in the console it doesn't get past the line that checks if an anchor exists before the current anchor. It has run all the way through once or twice but it didn't work regardless.

Comment: @Twisty I'll change your suggestions in a second, I'm seeing if sibling() works

Comment: The issue there is `$(this)` has no reference. What is that element?

Answer (score 0):

This was very ambiguous and hard to work out an example. Here is what I came up with:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/Lrzo071q/8/

**HTML**

```
<nav class="main-nav">
  <i class="fa fa-angle-left fa-5x prev" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="./page-1/" id="sub-1" class="sub-link"><h5>1<span class=""></span></h5></a></li>
    <li><a href="./page-2/" id="sub-2" class="sub-link"><h5>2<span class=""></span></h5></a></li>
    <li><a href="./page-3/" id="sub-3" class="sub-link"><h5>3<span class=""></span></h5></a></li>
    <li><a href="./_display/" id="sub-4" class="sub-link"><h5>4<span class=""></span></h5></a></li>
  </ul>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-right fa-5x next" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</nav>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  console.log("Small Screen Navigation Setup");
  var page_url = window.location.pathname,
    urlParts = page_url.split('/');
  console.log("URL:", page_url, "URL Parts:", urlParts);
  $(".sub-link").each(function(k, el) {
    var href = $(el).attr("href");
    console.log("Compare:", href, "to: ./" + urlParts[1] + "/");
    if (href == "./" + urlParts[1] + "/") { 
      console.log("Target URL found in Window URL");
      console.log("Current URL:", href);
      if ($(el).parent().is("li:last")) {
        console.log("Hidding Next.");
        $(".next").hide();
      }
      if ($(el).parent().is("li:first")) {
        console.log("Hidding Prev.");
        $(".prev").hide();
      }
    } else {
      console.log("Target URL not found.");
    }
  });
});
```

**Console**

```
Small Screen Navigation Setup
URL: /_display/ URL Parts: Array [ "", "_display", "" ]
Target URLs collected: Array [ "./page-1/", "./page-2/", "./page-3/", "./_display/" ]
Compare: ./page-1/ to: ./_display/
Target URL not found.
Compare: ./page-2/ to: ./_display/
Target URL not found.
Compare: ./page-3/ to: ./_display/
Target URL not found.
Compare: ./_display/ to: ./_display/
Target URL found in Window URL
Current URL: ./_display/
Hidding Next.
```

This of course will be different on your site. Had you included some sample of the output, this example could have been more specific. Basically, we want to compare the values in `href` against the current url. Using `.each()` we can iterate over each `<a>` and then compare the value of the `href` attribute to the a specific string that we have collected from `window.location.pathname`.

Once we have found the match, we want to test if it is the `:first` or `:last` element. We can do this by testing with `.is()`. Since we're iterating over `<a>` elements, and we need to test the `<li>` item, we need to look at our elements parent element using `.parent()`.

You will see output like:

```
< 1 2 3 4
```

A second test of this example would be to move `./_display/` to a different link:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li><a href="./_display/" id="sub-1" class="sub-link"><h5>1<span class=""></span></h5></a></li>
    <li><a href="./page-2/" id="sub-2" class="sub-link"><h5>2<span class=""></span></h5></a></li>
    <li><a href="./page-3/" id="sub-3" class="sub-link"><h5>3<span class=""></span></h5></a></li>
    <li><a href="./page-4/" id="sub-4" class="sub-link"><h5>4<span class=""></span></h5></a></li>
  </ul>
```

This will have output like:

```
1 2 3 4 >
```

Hope this helps.